# Change buffered image background

Tags: java, graphics, background, bufferedimage, transparent

I'm trying to create an logo resizer that also changes the color of the background of the logo to either white or transparent depending on user input.

This works to turn the background color of an image from transparent to white:

```
    BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(new File(inputImagePath)); //reads the input image
    BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, inputImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); //creates the output image

    Graphics2D image = outputImage.createGraphics(); 
    image.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    //sets background color to white
    image.fillRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    image.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
    image.dispose();

    String formatName = outputImagePath.substring(outputImagePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); //Finds what type of image it is

    ImageIO.write(outputImage, formatName, new File(outputImagePath)); //Creates the output image file in correct path
}
```

I thought if I changed it to this, it would change an images background color from white to transparent but instead it stays white. Any help?

```
    BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(new File(inputImagePath)); //reads the input image
    BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, inputImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); //creates the output image

    Graphics2D image = outputImage.createGraphics(); //Draws the actual output image
    image.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
    image.fillRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    image.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    image.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);   //Draws the actual output image
    image.dispose();

    String formatName = outputImagePath.substring(outputImagePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); //Finds what type of image it is

    ImageIO.write(outputImage, formatName, new File(outputImagePath)); //Creates the output image file in correct path
}
```

I'm thinking now that I might have to trace the logo and give it a whole new background itself, but that might prove to be very difficult. Any advice?

Comment: Is the original image already transparent?

Comment: The image is a logo with a white background and now I'm having trouble with turning into a logo with a transparent background.

Comment: You can’t clear an existing images background or at least not easily